# (Issue With Nested For Loop) Multiple Column 2 Per Column 1

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to implement THIS PARTICULAR nested for loop (I have used them before for a similar task). I need 4 user inputs (range of length and radius) and then I have to display a table of calculated values like so:

```
Radius Length Volume Area
1      1      *.**   *.**
1      2      *.**   *.**
1      3      *.**   *.**
2      1      *.**   *.**
2      2      *.**   *.**
2      3      *.**   *.**
```

As you can see, I need multiple lengths for each radius. I have spent hours stuck on trying to figure out *how* I could possibly get multiple "column 2" values for the same "column 1" value. My code isn't outputting the above, but rather outputs this:

```
[ Enter only positive integers! ]
Enter starting length: 1
Enter end length: 3
Enter starting radius: 1
Enter end radius: 3
Radius  Length  Volume  Area
1       1       3.14    6.28
1.00    1       3.14    6.28
1.00    1       3.14    6.28
1.00    1       3.14    6.28
```

Here's my code (originally, I wanted to put less and follow the "minimal code" guidelines, but I was afraid that I might miss important information if I just omitted everything outside the for loop. Sorry about that!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

// func prototyping
float volCalc(float pi, float rad, float len);
float surfCalc(float pi, float rad, float len);

int main()
{

    float pi = 3.14159265;
    int radStart, radEnd, lenStart, lenEnd;

    // data i/o
    cout << "[ Enter only positive integers! ]" << endl
         << "Enter starting length: ";
    cin  >> lenStart;
    cout << "Enter end length: ";
    cin  >> lenEnd; 
    cout << "Enter starting radius: ";
    cin  >> radStart;
    cout << "Enter end radius: ";
    cin  >> radEnd;

    cout << "Radius Length  Volume  Area" << endl;

    // for each radius, there will be lenStart to lenEnd calculations
    int totalRows = (radEnd - radStart) * (lenEnd - lenStart);

    for (int rows = 0; rows < totalRows; rows++) // iterate through all rows
    {

        // column iterator
        for (int i = lenStart; i < (lenEnd - lenStart); i++) 
        {
            float radius = radStart, length = lenStart;

            // outputting each row
            cout << radius << setprecision(2) << fixed << " "
                 << length << " " << volCalc(pi,radius,length) << " "
                 << surfCalc(pi,radius,length) << " " << endl;
            radius++;
            length++;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

float volCalc(float pi, float rad, float len)
{
    return (pi*rad*rad*len);
}

float surfCalc(float pi, float rad, float len)
{
    return (2.0f*pi*rad*len);
}
```

(P.S. Yes, this is part of the curriculum I am learning. I did try to search Stack Overflow, some other forums, and I tried sifting through some more documentation on the for loop, but I just can't seem to figure it out!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's tripping you up is trying to reason about this in terms of rows and columns. The loops you need don't map to rows and columns so I'd throw that mental model out. This problem's easier if you work directly with radii and lengths.

The trick with nested loops is that for each iteration of the outer loop you get multiple iterations of the inner one. The inner one loops quicker than the outer one. Looking at the output, when the radius is 1 we print three lines, one for each length. Then it moves to a radius of 2 and again prints three lines. The radius moves slowly, the length quickly.

That means that the slow outer loop should loop over radii:

```
for (int radius = radStart; radius <= radEnd; radius++)
```

And the fast inner loop over lengths:

```
for (int length = lenStart; length <= lenEnd; length++)
```

Combined you get:

```
for (int radius = radStart; radius <= radEnd; radius++)
{
    for (int length = lenStart; length <= lenEnd; length++)
    {
        cout << radius << setprecision(2) << fixed << " "
             << length << " " << volCalc(pi,radius,length) << " "
             << surfCalc(pi,radius,length) << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how am I supposed to easily figure out the range? I really appreciate your answer, but I don't get it.

Comment: Do you mean how do you know there will be 9 lines of output? It falls out naturally from the loops above: both loops iterate 3 times and the total number of iterations is the product of the two. 3 * 3 = 9. You don't have to calculate 9 at any point, it happens naturally.

Comment: Ah, no, the 9 lines of output naturally makes sense. I think it's hard to get that stupid rows/columns mental model out of my head, because I honestly had trouble grasping it. In my head: there is `length` rows for every `radius` column; the rows are the inner loop, the columns are the outer loop. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: No, you gotta ditch the rows/columns idea. It's only coincidence that there are two variables and tables are two-dimensional. If you have five variables you'd need five loops yet you could still use a two-dimensional table; there'd be more columns, not more dimensions.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand why it's bad to think of it as columns and rows after analyzing all of this more thoroughly. I appreciate your help!